# grep in bash doesn't show any results?

Tags: bash

I have a list of class names and I am trying to identify which of those does not appear in a set of config files. So I thought I could just write a little bash script to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    name=$line
    echo 'grep -R --include='definition.xml' '$name' ~/workspace/basedir/'
    if grep -R --include='definition.xml' '$name' ~/workspace/basedir/; then
        echo "output for $name"
    else
        echo "no output for $name"
    fi
done < $1
```

My problem is, if I copy and paste one of the echos with the grep command, then I am getting a result, but the grep itself (even without the if) just shows nothing. So right now I am just getting a lot of "no output for xyz" messages.

Hope you can help. :)

Comment: Don't use grep with XML, use an XML parser. If you provide some sample input, we can show you how to do this properly.

Comment: @TomFenech: I guess it's not the most efficient way, but it will be a one time thing and the files aren't really that big.

Comment: Double-quote `"$name"`. Single quotes prevent the variable `$name` from being used. You are passing `'$name'` literally to grep, not what is contained in the variable `$name`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ha, that looks good. :) If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: It catches us all every once in a while `:p`

Comment: It's not about efficiency, it's about using the right tool for the job. You may be able to get away with using grep in simple cases but it's worth learning how to use an XML parser if you work with the format regularly.

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks for your concern. I know how to use an xml parser, but the right tool in this case is the one that gets the job done with the minimum of development time, even if grepping would take 10 minutes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-quote `"$name"`. Single quotes prevent the variable `$name` from being used. You are passing `'$name'` literally to grep, not what is contained in the variable $name.